# Proof of a property of PID

Tags: abstract-algebra

Property: If $F$ is an integral domain and $c$ is an irreducible element in $F$, then $F[x]$ is not a PID(principal ideal domain.

I saw the property in my textbook, but I wander how to proof it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that in a PID each non-zero prime ideal is maximal.

Note that $(X)$ is a prime ideal in $F[X]$ that is not maximal; as $F[X]/(X)$ is isomporphic to $F$ which is a domain (by assumption) yet not a field (as it contains an irreducible element).

More explicitly, you could argue that $(c,X)$ cannot be generated by a singel element.

Comment: May I ask one more thing, how can I use it to proof $F[x_{1},x_{2}]$ is not a PID?

Comment: I assume here you mean $F$ is a field. In this case, apply the result we just just established with $F_1 = F[X_1]$, which is  a domain with an irreducible, for example $X_1$. And note that $F[X_1,X_2] = F_1 [X_2]$. So by the just established fact it is not a PID. Alternatively you could show that (X_1,X_2) is not generatd by a single element, or $(X_2)$ is prime but not maximal. (Yet the first seems intended by your source.)

Comment: As the comment under, Is $F_{1}$ field/integral domain?

Comment: If $F$ is a field (or also just an integral domain) then the polynomial ring $F[X]$ is an integeral domain, as the product of two non-zero polynomials is nonzero, yet not a field as a non-constant polynomial does not admit a (polynomial) multiplicative inverse.

Comment: So, $F[X]$ is just a inegral domain. How can I say $X_{1}$ is irreducible in $F[X_{!}]$, then $F[X_{1},X_{2}]$ is not a PID?

Comment: This is the content of the question you just asked. $F[X_1]$ is an integeral domain that contains and irreducible element. The argument in my answer show that then $F[X_1][X_2]$ is not a PID. And $F[X_1][X_2]= F[X_1,X_2]$

Comment: I don't understand why $F[X_{1}]$ is an integeral domain with irreducible element, then $F[X_{1},X_{2}]$ is not a PID. If $F[X_{1}]$ is not a field, then I can't apply the question in the beginning. Besides, you said $(X_{1},X_{2})$ is not generated by a singal element, or (X_{2}) is prime but not maxiaml (How does it come from my source?)

Comment: You can apply the question. In your orginal question it is not assumed that $F$ is a field. In fact it is not a field as it contains the irreducible element $c$. You apply your orginal question with  $F[X_1]$ playing the role of $F$  and $X_1$ that of $c$. // The last two assertions do not follow directly from what we discussed. It would be an alternative argument. You can ignore this.

Answer (score 2):

$F[x]$ is PID $\Rightarrow (x)$ is a maximal ideal $\Longrightarrow F \cong F[x]/(x)$ is a field.

Answer (score 1):

$F[x]$ is a PID if and only if $F$ is a field. But a field does not admit an irreducible element.

Comment: May I ask one more thing, how can I use it to proof $F[x_{1},x_{2}]$ is not a PID?

Comment: $F[x_1]$ is not a field, hence $F[x_1][x_2]$ is not a PID. In terms of you original question: $x_1$ is irreducible in $F[x_1]$.